# building mono-complete 4.6.2 for linux mint 20

Tags: linux, mono

Hi the mono docs on the mono-project site are a bit vague  to non existent on installation on linux
I want to try installing mono-4.6.2 amd64  on linux mint 20 , which had mono-6.8
I've tried the obvious of loading all the repos for tricia (bionic) on the apt source list
with all the current repos hashed out.
the problem I'm trying to solve is memory leaks , which after sqlite , mono is also causing.

APT used to respond to wildcards, looks like that has gone, and loading dependent packages
is not working well.
I have the current mono-6.8 removed, and I have downloaded MonoFramework MDK-4.6.2
that packed contains mono.pkg,Resources,and distribution.
Where do I find the info for installing in linux, or someone here who can provide that info
please
linux Mint 19.3 was a great edition , very stable, but linux mint 20 is the inverse :(
I'm finding lots of problems, and I know I'm not alone.
Thanks

Comment: With all the efforts you described, you probably could already fully migrate your code to .NET Core, a far better and future proof platform.

Answer (score 0):

So obviously the first comment you get when you ask about a technology more than  5 year old on stack overflow is to migrate to another one, namely .NET Core here.

Well, migrating a big project from Mono to .Net Core is harsh, so if the only problem you have is performance / memory leak  issues when upgrading mono versions, it's worth wondering **if your linux kernel is up-to-date** ?  For me it was the main issue. after upgrating kernel from 3.16 to 4.19, mono/mod_mono in latest versions are running like a charm,  and I regret everyday having spent so much time and efforts on migrating to .Net Core, migrating one by one the many 3rd party libraries that were unmaintened or without .Net Core support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think my kernel is that old

Linux richard-Inspiron-3580 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Current version of mono is mono-6.10 , suspect libgdiplus from comments on github